# Autoload Stack Overflow on https

Tags: support, ssl

Why doesn't Stack Overflow loads on https automatically? I have to manually enter https every time I want to load https.

Comment: related [MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites), from 2011 and status planned

Comment: Do you expect the site by default to load over https? Or did it fallback to http where you didn't expect that to happen?

Comment: I want it to load https default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are still corner cases left to fix for Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange for that matter, to fully support [https](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites). That is the reason that by default loading everything over https is not going to happen soon if ever.

If you want Stack Overflow to load over https, make sure you have a shortcut/favorite in your browser that uses the https protocol instead of http. Be aware that you might be switched back to http in some cases.

There are certain plugins that force all your sessions to the secure protocol. One of them being [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/HTTPS-EVERYWHERE) but that tool is notorious for causing trouble, as can be learned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=https+everywhere)

Comment: I've been using HTTPSEverywhere plugin for chrome and it fails sometimes as well. And its only a workaround. When will SO actually automatically load on HTTPS? Its weird to see things like [this](https://twitter.com/ankitpopli1891/status/683993817213612032) while browsing SO.

Comment: When they are ready for it @AnkitPopli it is in the works for a long time but AFAIK it needs major changes in their url/site naming scheme to keep it manageable but that will break every current url out there. It is better than it was a year go. Still needs work.

Comment: That's good to know. Looking forward to it. Just curious as a developer what are the challenges in it? 1 year seems quite a long a time for this. Any idea?

Comment: Everything I know is found based on searches on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=https) and an occasional Tweet, chat message or comment from an SE developer.